# How to change Chrome icon in the Message Tray

Tags: gnome, chrome

I want the Chrome icon in the message tray to be bigger. Where is the icon file located?

Comment: Tried to ask your package manager where it put them? Mine says the icons are /usr/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps/chromium-browser.png (where the `*` glob stands in place of the 22x22, 24x24, 48x48, 64x64 and 256x256 sizes).

Comment: So we know its location, anyone knows how to show the 48x48 icon in the Message Tray?

Comment: When you resize the window manager will pick the right location.

Comment: How is it related to window manager?